# Generate 12 Digit HEX number in KSH

Tags: linux, scripting, solaris, ksh

I need to generate 12 digit Hex numbers in KSH on Solaris

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -A hex 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
for i in {1..12}
do
   printf ${hex[$((RANDOM%16))]}
done
```

Comment: Good solution except I would probably add an additional line before the loop, i.e. RANDOM=0x`head -c 4 /dev/urandom | od -x | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f6`

Comment: This is working good, I will give it a try once I am at work tomorrow 
Thanks

Comment: That should be modulus 16. You can omit the `$(())`: `${hex[RANDOM%16]}`. You can also do `hex=({0..9} {A..F})`. (These are true in ksh93. I'm not sure about earlier versions.)

Comment: This doesn't work on a Solaris box
/bin/ksh Version M-11/16/88i
/usr/dt/bin/dtksh Version M-12/28/93d

Tested on both 
SunOS 5.10 Generic_142901-11 i86pc i386 i86pc
SunOS 5.9 Generic_118558-27 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-280R

Answer (score 1):

Start with this Python program, `hex12.py`.

hex12.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import hashlib
h= hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()
print h[:12]
```

In your shell you can now use `hex.py` to create 12 hex digits on standard out.

Comment: @S. Lott, I believe he requires a solution using ksh script.

Comment: He asked for ksh, I think he needs a korn shell script

Comment: That works in ksh.  Try it.  If this has `x` permissions, then the `#!/usr/bin/env python` causes ksh to invoke Python.  Every time.  Reliably.  Indeed, it works in just about every shell.

Comment: @S. Lott, It's a mute point. You could write it in Java and it would work, he required a solution in KSH scripting language, otherwise I'm sure he would said something.

Comment: @Anders: It wouldn't trivially work in Java.  You have to compile it and make an executable JAR from it.  In Python, it works as if it's part of the ksh.

Comment: @S.Lott 
On Solaris I get the error
`  File "hex12.py", line 3, in ?
    import hashlib
ImportError: No module named hashlib`

With root-access this can be fixed, but it does not work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
DIGITS=`head -c 6 /dev/urandom | od -x | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/^0* //' -e 's/ //g'
```

Answer (score 0):

As RANDOM variable generates a 15 bit number (from 0 to 32767) you can concatenate several RANDOM values.

You will need a 48 bit number as 12 hex digits are `12 * 4 = 48` bits.

Either:

```
$ printf '%x\n' $(( ((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)<<15|RANDOM)<<3|RANDOM%8 ))
9142467b46d3
```

Or:

```
$ printf '%x' $((RANDOM%4096)) $((RANDOM%4096)) $((RANDOM%4096)) $((RANDOM%4096)); echo
808878c21e19
```